# Split string and store in a new string

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, client-server

My server receives a string message that is sent by the client. It receives the following in a string  [Process ID, Hostname, App Name, File Path]
 of the client. How should I split the received string into 4 types and store them individually in another string?

Comment: You could use [`String.split(char[] delims)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx), or that does not work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Split()` method and store them in `string[]` like

```
string[] data = "Process ID, Hostname, App Name, File Path".Split(',');
```

Comment: not really a great showcase, since there is no `,` in your string :)

Comment: @Andro, that's why the string in code is `string receive from client`

Comment: @Rahul We get that, and while your solution is correct the *example* is a poor one because if you literally compiled your example it's not actually going to split anything since it doesn't contain a comma. That's all Andro's saying.

Comment: @sab669, hope now it shows a good example.